# MATLAB Wlan toolbox- Queueing model

Tags: matlab, wifi, delay, simulink, queuing

I need to know what is the Queuing model in WLAN toolbox examples, specifically Simulink model: 802.11ax System-Level Simulation with Physical Layer Abstraction in system-level simulation. Nothing is mentioned in documentation and I need to calculate the queuing model matching to this.

Would appriciate any help.

Comment: Have you checked this information: https://www.mathworks.com/help/wlan/ug/802-11ax-system-level-simulation-with-physical-layer-abstraction.html?

Comment: Yes, and they don't provide any information regarding the queuing model. I need to know if it's M/M/1, M/M/S or ..